# npm run build does not pick up changes

Tags: reactjs, npm, build

I am building a react app and all worked fine until yesterday. I need to build the app in a production ready state, so i always run `npm run build`, but somehow when I change something in my page, the changes don't get picked up. If i do npm start, I can see the changes, but the files in the build folder don't contain the changes.
Does anyone know a fix?
Greets and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the node_modules and package_lock.json files. then run again `npm run build`.

Comment: is there a more permanent solution? Do not want to do this each time.

Comment: @Ravi Lavanjan, how does that work? If you remove node_modules, then you remove `react-script` and you will not be able to do an `npm run build`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and then realised that in my package.json -->scripts, the `start` command was set to `"serve -s build"`. I changed it back to `"react-scripts start"` and I recovered the hot-reloading feature. I hope this help.